# Solving $\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\prod^n_{k=1}{e^{-\frac{1}{k}}}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I show whether the following series is convergent or divergent?

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\prod^n_{j=0}{e^{-\frac{1}{j+1}}}}$$

**What I have so far:**

$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\prod^n_{j=0}{e^{-\frac{1}{j+1}}}}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}{e^{-\sum_{j=1}^n{\frac{1}{j}}}}
$$

I know that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{j}}=+\infty$ and I'm trying to use some inequality to show that my series is greater than something divergent, but I think I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $H_n = \sum_{j=1}^n{\frac{1}{j}}$ are the “harmonic numbers” and have well-known asymptotics, compare https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} \le \log n + 1.
$$
Hence
$$
-\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} \ge -\log n - 1.
$$
Can you proceed now?

Comment: Is that a natural logarithm, i.e. with base e?

Comment: @Nikola yes, it is

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \ln n +\gamma +\epsilon_n$$

(see [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))) with $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \epsilon_n =0$.

Hence your series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\prod^n_{j=0}{e^{-\frac{1}{j+1}}}}$$ look at the partial product 
$$a_n={\prod^n_{j=0}{e^{-\frac{1}{j+1}}}}=e^{-H_{n+1}}$$ So, $$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=H_{n+1}-H_{n+2}$$
Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers and continuing with Taylor expansion for large values of $n$
$$\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)=-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Now, still using Taylor
$$\frac{a_{n+1} } {a_n }=e^{\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n) }=1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{5}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{a_{n+1} } {a_n }=1$$